# Timeout exception calling UserPrincipal.GetGroups from a Windows service

Tags: wcf, active-directory, impersonation, userprincipal

When I run simple console app that calls UserPrincipal.GetGroups, it enumerates the users groups with no problems.  However when I run the same code as the same user on the same server but from a windows service hosting WCF, I get the following chain of errors:

```
Message : The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:10. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

    Inner Exception
    ---------------
    Message : The read operation failed, see inner exception.

                                Inner Exception
                                ---------------
                                Message : The socket transfer timed out after 00:00:10. You have exceeded the timeout set on your binding. The time allotted to this operation may have been a portion of a longer timeout.

                                   Inner Exception
                                   ---------------
                                   Message : A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
```

Could this have something to do with the WCF thread impersonation?  `WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name` returns the same user, however `Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name` is different - empty string in the case of the console app, but the impersonated WCF user in the case of the Windoes Service.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with thread impersonation per se. Does the account under which your windows service runs have appropriate permissions?

Comment: Definitely, as I mention when the code is run as a console app using the same account on the same machine, no exception.

Comment: @Bermo When you run the same program in the console, how long does it take to return from GetGroups()?  Is it more than 10 seconds?